# How i can add my td in the table as i want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <tbody>
    <tr class="th">
        <td>
            this is a heead
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Half Pallets
        </td>
        <td>4 Full Pallet
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>

        <td>4 Full Pallet
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Take a look,Suppose i want to add the tr for first tr.th then I want to set them on last tr then first tr.th but how I can do.

If their is multiple tr.th in table then I need to set the tr from last from second tr.th in my case.

Could you show me how I can do this.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to put a new `tr` in the table before `tr.th` if it exists, or at the end of the `table` if not?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my "mind reading" capabilities intended the question exactly as you explained! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some HTML like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="th">
            <td>Some header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some more data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="th">
            <td>Another header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some more data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I assume you want the resultant HTML to look like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="th">
            <td>Some header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some more data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A new bit of data in a new row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="th">
            <td>Another header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some more data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In that case, you could use the following jQuery:

```
var headerRows = $('tr.th');

if(headerRows.length > 1) {
    var headerRow = headerRows.get(1);
    $(headerRow).before('<tr><td>A new bit of data in a new row</td></tr>');
}
else if(headerRows.length == 1) {
    var headerRow = headerRows.get(0);
    $(headerRow).closest('tbody').append('<tr><td>A new bit of data in a new row</td></tr>');
}
else {
    // no header rows - do nothing?
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/3QFvs/)

Or, a fiddle that adds a new row before the next `<tr>` element with the class `th` when a `<tr>` element with the class `th` is clicked on: [**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/3QFvs/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you could do (i intended that you want to add a new `<tr>` to the end of the table: if the last `<tr>` has the class `th` you want to add the new `<tr>` before the `<tr class="th">` :

```
//get the last tr
var trLast = $('tr:last');
//create a tr to add
var trToAdd = $('<tr>');
//if the last tr has the class th
if(trLast.hasClass('th'){
   //add the new tr before the last
   trLast.before(trToAdd);
}else{
   //add the new tr after the last
   trLast.after(trToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Suppose i have two tr.th and I want to add it for first then it'should be last from second tr.th. so Add in the last tr between first tr.th and second tr.th for adding the tr for first tr.th.

Comment: @user1197366 what do you mean?You can update your question if you want